# Alexa Skill, credentials for non-oauth external services

Tags: credentials, alexa-skills-kit

I've played with a couple of Alexa skills, but there seems no chance of publishing either of them because they use external APIs for which there isn't a persistent access token. Account linking seems to assume that external accounts use an oauth2 or similar authentication system where the private credentials can be requested by a page on the server, and a the skill can use a rather less private access token.

Obviously it's not permissible for my lambda code to see other people's passwords.

One service I've connected to uses a session id which lasts only half an hour or so, the other actually uses a password in the call structure.

Has anyone found a way around this issue? I have to admit it seems impossible.